# wso2esb: SOAP call returns base64 encoded data

Tags: xml, soap, wso2, wso2-esb

I have setup a call to a SOAP webservice using WSO2ESBs WSDL-Endpoint. Unfortunately the reponse contains a base64 encoded string instead of the plain XML document.

This string is enclosed in <axis2ns1:binary xmlns:axis2ns1="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"> tags.

How can I modify the Endpoint and/or the Proxy to receive the response as XML?

Kind regards,
  Marc

The request to the service looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:bas="http://sap.com/xi/BASIS">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <bas:ConfigurationScenarioQueryRequest>
        <ConfigurationScenarioID>EOI_CS_OBI*</ConfigurationScenarioID>
      </bas:ConfigurationScenarioQueryRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The response received by WSO2 looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <axis2ns1:binary xmlns:axis2ns1="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">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</axis2ns1:binary>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If I send the same request via SoapUI I receive this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns2:ConfigurationScenarioQueryResponse xmlns:ns2="http://sap.com/xi/BASIS">
         <ConfigurationScenarioID>EOI_CS_OBI_GLOBE</ConfigurationScenarioID>
         <ConfigurationScenarioID>EOI_CS_OBI_GLOBE_Bestandsfuehrung</ConfigurationScenarioID>
         <ConfigurationScenarioID>EOI_CS_OBI_GLOBE_PMAuftrag</ConfigurationScenarioID>
         <ConfigurationScenarioID>EOI_CS_OBI_GLOBE_Einkauf</ConfigurationScenarioID>
         <LogMessageCollection/>
      </ns2:ConfigurationScenarioQueryResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I'd like WSO2ESB to behave the same like SoapUI.

Answer (score 0):

I think you  receive binary messages ()..Use [builder mediator](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB402/Builder+Mediator) to build the messages.;
Eg:

```
<sequence  name="buildseq">
    <builder>
        <messageBuilder contentType="XXX" class="XXX"
                        formatterClass="XXX"/>
        <messageBuilder contentType="XXX" class="XXX"
                        formatterClass="XXX"/>
    </builder>
</sequence>
```

Comment: integrating build mediator into my outsequence leads me to an exception during deployment (_org.apache.synapse.SynapseException: Unknown mediator referenced by configuration element : builder_).